# How to reuse itemID after being deleted

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Sorry not good in english, hope you all can understand and please help.

I have unique identity for each item.

In the program, it can only have 200 itemsID

For instance, when the user create the first item, the database will assign itemID 1 to the first item, itemID 2 to second item till itemID 200.

User can delete the items. For instance, user delete from itemID 1 to itemID 20. So when user create a new item, i want to reuse the itemID 1, may i know how can i do about it?

For fresh start, whenever user create new item, i will check database for the max item id then retrieve it and add 1.

```
mySql_ = "SELECT MAX(ITEM_ID) FROM ITEM";

Object returnValue = ExecuteSql(mySql_);

if (DBNull.Value.Equals(returnValue))
{
     ItemId += 1;
}
```

My table design structure is as follow

```
 CREATE TABLE ITEM (
 ID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 ITEMID NOT NULL
 ITEM_NAME
 )
```

The above will be my table structure. I only allowed to have maximum itemID of 200. For example, user have created 200 items (table will have itemID 1 to 200), So if user want to create more items, they delete from itemID 1 to itemID20. So the next time when user create item, the new item insert to table will be itemID1.

Comment: Do you have any code to show for this? It should be fairly simple for most data structures.

Comment: After creating items, you can create a new List/Array of items, and then if user deletes 1-20 you clone would stay unaffected, you can fetch the id from the second list/array. 
but pasting the code would be more helpful.

Comment: I doubt, if you really want it. Any `int` value allocates 4 bytes, either `int` is, say, `123` or `1234567890`. since `itemId` is a *system internal* value which is not supposed to be seen by end user, it can be long (and, may be, ugly) value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQl server and Identity. Identity fields do not reuse old values by default. You can reseed them with DBCC CHECKIDENT (orders, RESEED, 9)
That means you'll have to run the statement based on every DELETE.

Comment: Yes i am using sql server but i don't think is identity. It is just id for the item which should be able to recycled after the user delete the items. The purpose of reuse the itemID is because the maximum value allow is 200. I cannot exceed it. So user can choose to delete those unwanted. Those id is not visible to the user

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not a good idea to handle IDs yourself. Let SQL Server do this withan identity column. You *especially* shouldn't reuse IDs after delete if your ID is the orimary key. That will degrade insert and index performance. It is always most efficient to add primary key values at the end of the range.

Especially to query your `MAX(ID)` is not efficient. If you want to reuse IDs without compromising good DB design, you can create a table that contains your ID pool and link with a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE IDPool (
    ID TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    --More columns if you need them
)
```

This table contains one entry for each reusable ID, so in your case 200 entries with ID 1 to 200

Your item would look somehow like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Items (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    PooledID TINYINT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES IDPool(ID)
    --Your other columns
)
```

You can insert new items like this:

```
INSERT INTO Items (PooledID)
VALUES ((SELECT MIN(ID) FROM IDPool p WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Items i WHERE p.PooledID = i.ID
)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your approach is good. You should use **identity** field which is always unique and don't use old id's anyway. But if you really want to use your approach try to create one more attribute in database. Let's say **Hidden** field.

When user delete record in application you just update this row and set it as Hidden (**Hidden=1**).

When user create new record you again update this record and set it to visible (**Hidden=0**).

The you can build application based on this filed and you can show/hide/work with records in base of **Hidden** attribute.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for the reply. Ur solution seem like a good ideas. What if i have more than one record of hidden = 1, which one should i update? For instance i have itemID 1 to 20 with hidden = 1, i want to update itemID 1.

Comment: Then you can specify which one you want to update using where condition. So if you want to update for example itemid=1 you just you update YourTable set Hidden=0 where itemid=1.